# Are there inexpensive tools to monitor student iPad’s?

Tags: technology

I am a teaching assistant for a class in which students use tablet computers to advance their projects. Yet, sometimes, we need their attention and it can be difficult for them to focus on what I tell them with such distracting tools in hand.

I am looking for a way to monitor student iPads from a teacher's iPad or computer (restrict web browsing, being able to blank the screen and etc.). Any ideas that are relatively cheap? I know similar software exists for [computers](http://www.lanschool.com/ipad).

Comment: Why do you want to be able to do this?

Comment: Similar software exists for computers _that you own and control_.

Answer (score 14):

To some extent, I think **you may be asking the wrong question**. The students you are talking about grown up adults, fully capable of making choices and understanding the consequences. I wonder if your *actual* question is something like:

> [What are effective ways to deal with misuse of mobile devices in class?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7886/2700)

You'll notice there are quite a few answers on this question, which may solve you real practical problem, yet none of them involve monitoring the students’ devices or anything else. I suggest that you address your problem directly:

- tell the students your expectations,
- set up rules that will govern the use of electronic devices,
- enforce the rules when you are aware of a violation.

Frankly, **the fact that a student would be using an iPad for purposes other than you had planned, if it doesn't prevent him or the others from learning, is not a bad thing**. You can't think of everything, and surely some of the students will come up with creative yet constructive ways to use the device.

Comment: I have taught a few courses so far and we have a few policies in place for tablets/mobile phones/laptops. Very few students actually follow all the directives and frankly, we don't care as long as it doesn't disturb the class and in my experience it never has.